# Images and copy won't align

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Please take a look at this website:  http://jlwingert.com/seametrics.html
I didn't post the source code because it's quite lengthy.  The problem is the lower half of the page.

I'm supposed to clean up this website and noticed that the bottom half of the page has unaligned images and copy.  I've gone through the coding and I'm having the hardest time finding the problem.

I'd be appreciative if anyone could view the source & see if they could provide assistance to this novice!

Thank you!
Jen

Comment: Nested tables, `<font>` tags.. 'Clean up' for sure!

Comment: Learn CSS and re-write it. It'll make your life MUCH more bearable.

Answer (score 2):

You start a new table @ WMX Series rather than continuing the existing one that has a 150px padding column.  That's the problem.  Also be ready for the "don't use tables" crowd to flame you.

Comment: Line 143: <tr><table><td><a href="http://www.seametrics.com/product/detail?sku=WMX101">

Comment: Thanks Sean.  Unfortunately I'm still having problems with the coding.  I'm relatively new to coding, so please excuse my silly questions.  Do I basically need to start from scratch at the WMX series?

Comment: @user608995 There's not enough room or formatting options in the comment to help you unfortunately. As @theChrisKent points out, you've got an HTML issue too (tags in the wrong order). So in addition to creating a new table, rather than adding rows to the existing table, you've got malformed HTML in there.  What tool are you using to develop this? Microsoft gives you a free tool (http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) that might help you. BUT you are going to need to learn (a lot) more to make it work right for you. **Hire someone with HTML skills.**